# Android unable to set a specific date to start a funciton

Tags: android

If I change the parameter in the function "scheduleAtFixedRate" from 0 to date, it will execute the function updateProfile every millisecond such as 2013/02/13 11:55:0001 ...0002...0003...

But What I want is that the updateProfile will execute only once after the date "2013/02/13 11:55:00". And the function will execute in every 5 second.

Why the change will cause that incident?

*ps the updateProfile function is executed on the background ini a new thread.

```
        try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("2013/02/13 11:55:00");

        TimerTask updateProfile = new Controller(context);
                    //timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, 0, 5000);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, date, 5000);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```